# Ruby Wrapper Error "require: error command not found"

Tags: ruby

I read other posts about "require error" but I think it's different so I ask you in a separate topic.
I made a script in ruby executed from a software that have a limited environment so I tryed different ways to execute this:

First Try:

I put the absolute path to ruby:

```
#!/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
```

but this give error:

```
"/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require': cannot load such file -- mail (LoadError)\n\tfrom /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'\n\tfrom /opt/script/script.rb:6:in `<main>'\n"
```

Second Try:

I create a wrapper and put the absolute path to ruby wrapper:

```
#!/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.1@script/ruby
```

That in a Centos6 Works while in a Centos5 (Elastix) give me the error:

```
"/opt/script/script.rb: line 4: require: command not found\n/opt/script/script.rb: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('\n/opt/script/script.rb: line 14: `def logger(message)'\n"
```

Where is the error?? I create a wrapper in this way:

```
rvm gemset create script
rvm gemset use script
gem install mail
```

Thanks for your help.
p.s. in a full environment shell the script works in both the machine (Centos 5 and 6) so I think I can exclude script problem

Comment: What command are you using to run the program? `require` is inbuilt functionality of the language, not somethint to install.

Comment: the command is: ./script.rb param1 param2  | The error left me think that the script on Centos 5 can't read the #! line and try to launch it as bash script instead ruby script | but I can't understand why on Centos 6 works and on Centos 5 no

Comment: That's what I was thinking, too. It almost sounds environment-variable-related, but I don't know of anything Ruby-related and am not well-versed in CentOS. If you throw "echo $0" before the `require`s, it shows the script name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand my problem so I write a solution here.
The problem it's not related to Ruby but to Linux, the clue was in the character @ in shebang line that was not interpretated so the script was executed as bash file.
I try to to find a way to escape this character to not write in launch string the full path of interpreter.
In Centos 5 there is this limitation that in Centos 6 was disappear.